# How to disable making a POST request when I hit Enter in one of text_field_tag in a form_for

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, dom-events

I have form_for and inside of which I have few text_field_tag. When I hit enter in one of *_tag, it does a POST request to provided URL, which I would like to disable it and do something else.

```
  <%= form_for 'sample', :url => sample_path, :remote => true do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :field_1, nil, :class => 'input', :onKeyPress=>"return disableEnterKey(event)" %>
    <%= text_field_tag :field_2, nil, :class => 'input', :onKeyPress=>"return disableEnterKey(event)" %>
      <%= submit_tag "Send", :id => 'send', :class => 'floatright' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

and here is `disableEnterKey()`:

```
disableEnterKey = function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
        //do somethig else
    }
  };
```

this `disableEnterKey` is getting called, but so is POST request.
How can I disable the default `onKeyPress` and overwrite the event?

Ruby: "1.8.7"

Rails: 3.2.8

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

So it will look like this:

```javascript
disableEnterKey = function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
        e.preventDefault();
        //do somethig else
    }
  };
```

Comment: that worked but e.preventDefault(); needs to be at the end of the function, in my case after //do something else.

Answer (score 0):

solved, if you have return false; in the end of disableEnterKey, then it won't make a POST request as well. thanks @ujm for quick feedback!

Comment: Works but bad practice.  Making use of .preventDefault() is the correct behavior he is trying to limit.